# Searching AnatomyData efficiently

Tags: anatomyplot3d

I really like `AnatomyPlot3D`, but find it exceedingly difficult to find *Mathematica*'s terminology for an anatomical structure.  Listing all of them and searching by eye is hopelessly burdensome, and free-form input rarely seems to work.

Here's a figure I'm working on, to show how the human voice produces sound:  lungs (blue) force air through the windpipe or trachea (green), through the vocal folds, through the nasal cavity, over the tongue and out the mouth:

```
AnatomyPlot3D[
 {ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Head"],
  AnatomyStyling[<|Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Lung"] -> Blue|>],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Lung"],
  AnatomyStyling[<|Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Tongue"] -> Yellow|>],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Tongue"],
  AnatomyStyling[<|Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Trachea"] -> Green|>],
  AnatomyStyling[<|Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Larynx"] -> Orange|>],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Larynx"],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Trachea"],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Esophagus"],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Neck"],
  AnatomyStyling[<|Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "VocalFold"] -> Blue|>],
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "VocalFold"]},
 AnatomySkinStyle -> Directive[LightBrown, Opacity[.2]],
 ViewPoint -> Left,
 PlotRange -> All,
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

However, I simply cannot find "VocalFold", "NasalCavity", or their equivalents.

So I'd appreciate it if someone could post these anatomical structure names for this figure.

But my real question is:  How does one systematically find the technical name for specific structures in *Mathematica*'s AnatomyData database without listing them all and searching "by eye"?

A sometimes useful solution is to plot a full section of the body (e.g., `Head`) the click on the portion you need and read it off.  Helpful.

Comment: Is what you're looking for related to these `EntityValue[Entity["AnatomicalStructure","VocalFold"],{"AlternateNames","LatinName","Name","UMLSConceptID"}]` or any of `Entity["AnatomicalStructure","VocalFold"]@"Properties"`?  What do you mean by "technical name for specific structures in Mathematica's AnatomyData database"?  Can you give examples?

Comment: @Adam:  "AlternateNames" is quite useful... thanks ($+1$).  But I tried your form with "Nasal Cavity" and got {{"cavity of nose"}, {"cavitas nasi"}, "nasal cavity", 
 Entity["AnatomicalConceptIdentifier", "C0027423"]}, alas none of which I could get to plot.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming OP wants an easier way to find **entities with non-Missing graphics 3d**, I ran

```
EntityValue[\
  EntityClass["AnatomicalStructure","BodyParts"],\
  EntityProperty["AnatomicalStructure","Graphics3DPrimitives"],\
  "NonMissingEntityAssociation"]
```

which yielded 138 body parts.  I believe the class `"BodyParts"` can be expanded to capture more entities, but this seemed like a good start.

Indeed, `nose=Entity["AnatomicalStructure","Nose"]` had a 3D model.  Then

```
nose@"RegionalParts"
```

yielded `inose=Entity["AnatomicalStructure","InternalNose"]`.  Then `graphics=inose@"Graphics3D"` is

[image: internal nose bones]

where there is a middle bone and two "septal nasal cartilages".  Evidently, there is no 3D model for the nasal cavity.  Perhaps it is computable with clever region complements of existing skin parts?